# Making 2 sticky divs and one scrollable

Tags: html, css, sticky

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want to have a sticky header, below it and adjacent to it a sticky div (which will contain an image, and it's height may vary, depending on the attached image size); below this sticky image container I want to have a div which will contain a gallery of smaller divs, and the gallery div must be scrollable, of course. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id="header_content">Header title</div>
</header>

<section>
<div id="div_main_image_container">
    <div id="div_main_image">
        <img id="img_main" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img543/2281/iu7x.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">1</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">2</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">3</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">4</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">5</div>
    <div class="div_item_container">6</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family:Verdana, Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

header { background:#000; height:60px; left:0; position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; }
#header_content{ line-height:60px; margin:0 auto; width:785px; color:#fff; }

section
{
  height:auto;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:60px;
}

#div_main_image_container
{
  margin:auto;
  width:785px;
  color:#399;
  background-color:#E0E0E0;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}

#div_main_image
{
  margin:5px;
  width:775px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:3px;
}

#div_main_image img { border-radius:3px; }

#gallery
{
  margin:auto;
  width:785px;
  color:#399;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.div_item_container
{
  width:235px;
  padding:5px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:25px;
  background-color:#E0E0E0;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.div_item_container:nth-child(3n+0) { margin-right:0; }
```

Here's the full working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/272ww/5/

I can't make the gallery div be scrollable. I tried to place it outside the , but I can't make it to be exactly below the sticky image div. I also can't make it be fixed in a position, since the image div's height may change from image to image.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update css**

```
section
   {
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:60px;
   }
    #div_main_image_container
    {
        position:fixed;
        top:80px;
        margin:auto;
        width:785px;
        margin-left:50%;
        left:-392px;
        color:#399;
        background-color:#E0E0E0;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    }
```

**jQuery to Set Position**

```
var headerHeight = $('#header_content').outerHeight(),
        imgHeight = $('#div_main_image_container').outerHeight();
        myPaddingTop = headerHeight + imgHeight;
    $('#gallery').css({
        paddingTop: myPaddingTop
    })
```

**[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/272ww/9/)**

Comment: Thanks, but again, the main image div, `<div id="div_main_image_container">`, has to be sticky as well, the gallery has to be scrolled below it.

Comment: Yup, pretty much what I needed, just did the same thing, just rearranged the HTML and CSS a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/272ww/12/ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to remove position:fixed; from your section, that will make page scrollable. As for the other contents, I'm afraid I need further explanation :(

Comment: I tried it before I asked the question, it does make the page scrollable, but then the main image scrolls as well, while it has to be fixed below the header. Only div with id "gallery" has to be scrollable (with all its content).

Comment: something like that? Where the scrollable content flows on top of the fixed content above? http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/272ww/10/. Or the scroll only happens at the bottom. In that case, I would suggest making the div itself scrollable. Please note, I have not fixed the look of it or refine it any further, just making sure this is what you wanted first.

Comment: It's closer to what I need, yes. The gallery has to be centered and scroll below the image container (easily fixed with z-index, i guess).

Comment: Rakesh answer is better in that it allows for image that has a different height as you have requested